# QTopengl c++ simple 2d app

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 2d

Im trying to make a simple 2D application, and our image processing professor has told us to use opengl. Im working with c++ and QT.

I want to open a simple window that holds a place where I can draw points of different colors. All by code, there is no user interaction. I cant use any other library, can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out :
http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter14.html

Answer (score 1):

[2D Painting Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/opengl-2dpainting.html) using [QGLWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qglwidget.html).

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a library to render. You need at least one or two more (at least to create a window).

Since that is a homework, take a look at [this example](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=03) on how to do your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Qt comes with numerous examples of using QGLWidget.